# Specificity of Jackson vs Json OR "Why is this a good reply?"

Tags: json, jackson

I'm pretty new to Jackson & Json but I have worked with it already, mainly using object mappers, always defining my own classes and working very object oriented. Recently, I decided to teach myself some Android programming and - in the the process - to query data from a 3rd party webservice that uses JSON encoding for their replies. One of those replies confounds me.

I query for a number of objects, and get something like this:

```
JSON: 
[
  {"num":"2","total":"2"},
  {"id":"1234", ...more fields...},
  {"id":"1235", ...more fields...}
]
```

This is something that doesn't parse well with my standard Jackson approches, since, from the way i read it, this indicates the start of an array with the first element being of a different type than that of the following elements. I am currently unable to model this as a POJO to allow for standard Jackson mapping. (and honestly speaking, I didn't think it was correct syntax) I can still work around this easily with some basic string editing, but I figure I must have misunderstood something. Pardon me if this is a silly question. I appreciate your help and I'm really looking forward to your responses.

Edit 1: Thanks to [Hot Licks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/581994/hot-licks), who confirmed my self doubts =). Can someone suggest a proper way to model this in Jackson, or is this really a case of jackson being more specific than JSON?

Comment: Perfectly legal [JSON](http://www.json.org/).  The elements of an array do not need to all be of the same type.  You can mix arrays, "objects", strings, and numbers in the same array.

Comment: Thank's a lot. So, is there a way to model that with Jackson?

Comment: I've never used Jackson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this:

1. Is it legal JSON
2. Is it a sensible data representation

For the first question answer is "yes"; the second one is subjective. I would claim "no", because there is no real typed structure in Java (or Javascript for that matter), aside from very generic "List of Maps"; so it is not really an object model, just an odd data model for JSON.

So while you can obviously bind this using Jackson to something like:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> list = (List<Map<String,Object>>) mapper.readValue(jsonSource, List.class);
```

it will be bit cumbersome to use.

However. you can use two-step processing: first into above-mentioned "untyped" List; and then convert Maps to actual Objects you want, like:

```
Iterator<Map<String,Object>> it = list.iterator();
HeaderOb header = mapper.convertValue(it.next(), HeaderOb.class); // has 'num' and 'total'
while (it.hasNext()) {
  ValueOb value = mapper.convertValue(it.next(), ValueOb.class); // has 'id', others
}
```

The reason there is no single-phase method is that, well, JSON structure described above has no natural Object mapping. Whoever designed it was not thinking through implications of choosing such a structure, or perhaps wasn't very adept at OO.

For what it is worth, a more common model used for stuff that JSON sample contains would be something like:

```
{
  "num" : 2,
  "total" : 2,
  "entries" : [
     { "id": ... },
     ...
  ]
}
```

which would easily map to Java objects as well.

Comment: This leaves no question open =) Thank you very much for this in-depth answer!